# True or false: $A \subseteq B \iff A^c \cup B=\Omega$, and $(A-B)^c = A^c \cup B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I've got to solve the following problem:

> Let be $A$, $B$, $C$ subsets of $\Omega$. Determine whether the following statements are true or false. Give a demonstration if the statement is true, and a counterexample if it is false.
>
> 1. $A \subseteq B \iff A^c \cup B=\Omega$.
> 2. $(A-B)^c = A^c \cup B$.

In order to avoid missunderstoods, let be fixed that, $\forall A,B$ sets:

> $A - B = \{x: x\in A \land x\notin B\}$
>
> $X^c = \Omega - X$

How can I solve them?
The further I've got to is:

> $[x \notin A \lor x\in B \iff x\in \Omega] \Longleftrightarrow A\subseteq B$

of the first statement.

PS: Sorry if my vocabulary in English isn't perfect.

Comment: Hint for $\Longrightarrow$ of 1: $A^{c} \cup A = \Omega$ and since $A \subseteq B$...

Comment: Have you tried drawing venn diagrams?

Comment: Hint 2: You can use $A- B = A\cap B^{c}$, (why?).

Comment: Draw Venn diagrams to convince yourself of the fact that $A \cup A^c = \Omega$, $A \cap A^c = \emptyset$, and that $A \subset B$ **iff** $B^c \subset A^c$.

Comment: Thank you all, I've got 2 and 1 $\Rightarrow$). But 1 $\Leftarrow$)? Can I apply the same argument in the opposite direction? PS: Yes, I had drawn venn diagrams for both of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $A \subseteq B \to A^c \cup B=\Omega$

$A \subseteq B \to A^c \cup B\supseteq A^c \cup A=\Omega$

> $A^c \cup B=\Omega \to A \subseteq B$

$A^c \cup B=\Omega \to A^c \supseteq \Omega-B\to (A^c)^c \supseteq (\Omega-B)^c\to A\subseteq B$

> $(A-B)^c = A^c \cup B$

$(A-B)^c = A^c \cup (A \cap B) = (A^c \cup A) \cap (A^c \cup B) = \Omega \cap (A^c \cup B) = A^c \cup B$